# Charts/Graphs not showing up in SSRS

Tags: graph, reporting-services, charts

I have designed several reports using Visual Studio 10.  These reports include many graphs, charts, etc. and they work perfectly on my local machine.  However, when I upload the reports to Reporting Server and try to run a report, it seems to hang for a minute or so, then the report displays, minus the graphs.  There is an outline of where the graph is supposed to be, with a little picture icon in the upper left corner.  I have appropriate permissions, so, not sure what is going one.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say proper permissions what do you mean. Are you using the ReportViewer or the reporting services API?

Comment: Report Viewer.  I go to http://myservername/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx